# Transition inhibition with Netlogo "Go" procedure

Tags: netlogo

I have two procedures (Levy Walk and Correlated Random Walk movement strategies, each with their own buttons for debugging purposes, as well as their own parameter sets on the netlogo interface), but I have also embedded both the aforementioned procedures in a single "Go" procedure for batch simulation processing in the following code implementation:

```
    to setup
     clear-all
     create-turtles 100 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
     reset-ticks
    end  

    to Correlated-Random-Walk
       rt random 360
       fd 1
    end

    to Levy-Walk
       rt random 90
       fd 2
    end

     to go
      Correlated-Random-Walk
      tick
      if ticks = 1000 [
       setup
       stop
       Levy-Walk
       if ticks = 1000 [
       setup  
       stop
       ]
      ]
    end
```

The above section of the "Go" procedure code is supposed to take the correlated random walk procedure and execute it for the entire duration (1000 ticks) of the simulation, then stop, reset (setup) the world and execute the levy walk procedure to the entire duration of the simulation (also a 100 ticks), then stop. As it is now, the code executes for the correlated random walk but does not go on to the levy walk procedure. It simply repeats the Correlated Random Walk procedure. What might the issue be?

Comment: Alan's fix below will do what you want (running 1000 ticks of one walk, then 1000 ticks of the other walk) but tick counter will run from 0 to 2000. Since you are throwing away the position at tick 1000 and starting again for the other scenario, have you considered just having a choose (or even switch) for which walk method to use, and simply running the model twice (manually or BehaviorSpace)? Such an approach would maintain the fundamental code separation between intialisation (ie setup) and simulation (ie go) actions. It would also generalise better if you wanted additional types of walks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `stop` command will stop the `go` procedure.  (See the docs.)  Does the following meet your needs?

```
to go1000each
  repeat 1000 [Correlated-Random-Walk tick]
  setup
  repeat 1000 [Levy-Walk tick]
end
```

If you make a button for this, it should *not* be a forever button.